# Dimming the main view when called Popover

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

There is a basic form, pressing button call method `performSegueWithIdentifier` which shows the popover window.  How could I black out (dim)  the main view window until the popover is active?

I've tried to use the library [SVProgressHUD](http://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD)  like this:

```
- (IBAction)publishButtonAction:(id)sender {
    [SVProgressHUD showWithMaskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeBlack];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"fbshareSigue" sender:self];
    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
}
```

Obtained for a split second - until there is a popover-window.

Where must I insert this code, if I try this?:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"fbshareSigue"]) {
        OFAFBShareViewController *svc = (OFAFBShareViewController *) [segue destinationViewController];
        UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *popoverSegue = (UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue;
        svc.postBlock = self.postInitBlock;
        [svc setClosePopWindow:[popoverSegue popoverController]];
    }
}

    - (IBAction)publishButtonAction:(id)sender {
        UIView *dimView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
        dimView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        dimView.alpha = 0.5f;
        dimView.tag = 1111;
        dimView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        [self.view addSubview:dimView];

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"fbshareSigue" sender:self];
}

  /* This code should be put in the other method where you are removing the popup.. Because it will remove the dim view. here is the wrong place for this code*/  

 /* for (UIView *view in [self.view subviews]) {
        if (view.tag == 1111) {
            [view removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }*/
```

Dim doesn't work...

====================

I have View `OFAResultViewController` that calling Popover (`OFAFBShareViewController`):

```
...
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"fbshareSigue"]) {
        OFAFBShareViewController *svc = (OFAFBShareViewController *) [segue destinationViewController];
        UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *popoverSegue = (UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue;
        svc.postBlock = self.postInitBlock;
        [svc setClosePopWindow:[popoverSegue popoverController]];
    }
}

- (IBAction)publishButtonAction:(id)sender {
    UIView *dimView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
    dimView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    dimView.alpha = 0.5f;
    dimView.tag = 1111;
    dimView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:dimView];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"fbshareSigue" sender:self];    
}
...
```

In `OFAFBShareViewController` I'm trying to close the dim view:

```
...
- (IBAction)cancelButtonAction:(id)sender {
    [closePopWindow dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    for (UIView *view in [self.view subviews]) {
            if (view.tag == 1111) {
                [view removeFromSuperview];
            }
}
...
```

But it doesn't work again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code, when you display the popup.

In OFAFBShareViewController

```
- (void) loadView
{
       [super loadView]; 
       UIView *dimView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
        dimView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        dimView.alpha = 0.5f;
        dimView.tag = 1111;
        dimView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        [self.view addSubview:dimView];
}
```

After popup removed, delete this view from super view using the tag.

After iOS 5.0 there is a public API method also introduced:

======================================================

To remove the view you can use this code:

```
 for (UIView *view in [self.view subviews]) {
                if ([view.tag == 1111]) {
                    [view removeFromSuperview];
                }
            }
```

Leave your Remove Dim View code as it is. Only Change `super.view` to `self.view` again.

It'll work for you then.

Hope it works for you...

Comment: Excuse me - "After popup removed, delete this view from super view using the tag." - How?

Comment: [self.view removeFromSuperview]; not work - black screen is still present

Comment: It looks like you are adding dimview in Other View Controller & removing it in another view controller. Thats why it is not working.

Comment: Then I do not understand how to do it. Could not help me, step by step?

Comment: (in [super.view subviews]) replace "self.view" with "super.view" & let me know if it works.

Comment: This code insert in parent view or in popover? In which metod: viewWillDisapear, viewDidDisappear etc.? If in popover, which metod? Or in my code for close popover in popover controller - (IBAction)cancelButtonAction:(id)sender?

Comment: In Your Code, cancelButtonAction method.

Comment: Can you provide me your code? mail me at sumit.kr.singh14@gmail.com. I'll do it for you and let you know your issue.

Comment: I have Modified my Answer. Now it'll work for you. Please check.

Comment: Where I must insert -(void)loadView method and where call this method? If I insert content of -(void)loadView in method viewDidLoad on the OFAFBShareViewController, then dim view is small, on size of popover-view and position in popover-view, not at the background.....

Comment: Hi, Actually i can send you, but the issue is i am working on OLD Xcode version without iOS 6.0. Hence i opened your project but didnt made any change into it. But rectified your issue and added my suggestion on that. Hope it works for you..

Comment: Above viewDidLoad method you can use loadView method. Its a view life Cycle method like viewDidLoad. It executes before viewDidLoad.

Comment: I trying it. But dim view appear on the popover-view (OFAFBShareViewController), not the main view (OFAResultViewController). Need dim main view (OFAResultViewController), then appear popover-view over the main and dim views, than dissapear popover and dim views. :-( But anyway thank you for your help!

Comment: I understand that I torment. :-) But anyway thank you for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

When you create the popover, add a dim view to the current view, and add the current view as a UIPopoverControllerDelegate of the popover controller:

1. Add the dimView:

   ```
   let dimView = UIView(frame: view.frame)
   view.addSubview(dimView)
   dimView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
   dimView.alpha = 0.5
   dimView.tag = 1234
   dimView.userInteractionEnabled = false
   view.addSubview(dimView)
   ```
2. Add the origin view as delegate of the popoverController:

   ```
   popoverViewController!.delegate = self
   ```

Then, in order to remove the dimView when the popover is dismissed, set the current view as implementing the UIPopoverControllerDelegate, and implement the popoverControllerDidDismissPopover func. Inside this function, remove the dimView:

```
extension MyOriginViewController: UIPopoverControllerDelegate {

    func popoverControllerDidDismissPopover(popoverController: UIPopoverController) {
        for subView in view.subviews {
            if subView.tag == 1234 {
                 subView.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
    }
}
```